# Embeded arguments with Kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Is there a way to have embedded arguments, and pass kwargs to the function?

For example:

Robot file

```
Testcase1
    do something "value" extra_args=bla
```

Python library

```
@keyword('do something "${value}"')
def do_something(self, value, **kwargs):
    print(value)
    print(kwargs)
```

Though the above way does not work. I've also tried with

```
Testcase1
    do something "value"    extra_args=bla
```

Also

```
*** Variables ***
    &{DICT}        extra_args=bla

Testcase1
    do something "value"    &{DICT}
```

And many other combinations. I've found pull request in Robotframework where this limitation was added,  but I am sure other Library writers must want this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no, that is not allowed; [doc link, the last paragraph in Basic Syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name).

Thinking about it, I can see where does this limitation come from - if kwargs *were* supported in keywords with embedded arguments, the parser would have very hard time, mainly in two regards:

- Where to break up the arguments as separate variables?

In this sample code:

```
My keyword @{kwarg} varies
    Pass Execution
```

, when called like this:

```
My keyword was called varies
```

, what should the arguments be - one with value `was called`, or two - `was` and `called`?

- Matching the target keyword

Another sample keywords definition:

```
My keyword @{kwarg}
    Pass Execution

My keyword ${normal} argument
    Pass Execution
```

, when called like this:

```
My keyword one argument
```

, which of the two keywords should the parser match?

As you can see kwargs in the embedded syntax would cause problems, and this is probably only the tip of the iceberg.

---

Side note - though I personally find keywords with embedded arguments mega cool - you can have calls that look like plain English! almost no other language gives you this possibility!, with practice I have found them limiting, and now try to avoid them.
Two reasons - you cannot change the signature of such keyword in the future, e.g. add optional arguments (or kwargs ;)). The second is the arguments are always passed on as string objects - so you'll have to cast them in the keyword if it deals with another type, and forget about ever passing complex object types.

Comment: Thanks for responding and confirming its not possible!

Answer (score 0):

In the Robot Framework documentation this is described in section [Free keyword arguments (**kwargs)](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-keyword-arguments-kwargs).

> Robot Framework 2.8 added the support for free keyword arguments using
>   Python's **kwargs syntax. How to use the syntax in the test data is
>   discussed in Free keyword arguments section under Creating test cases.
>   In this section we take a look at how to actually use it in custom
>   test libraries.

This is the Python example:

```
def various_args(arg, *varargs, **kwargs):
    print 'arg:', arg
    for value in varargs:
        print 'vararg:', value
    for name, value in sorted(kwargs.items()):
        print 'kwarg:', name, value
```

and the corresponding Robot File:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Positional
    Various Args    hello    world                # Logs 'arg: hello' and 'vararg: world'.

Named
    Various Args    arg=value                     # Logs 'arg: value'.

Kwargs
    Various Args    a=1    b=2    c=3             # Logs 'kwarg: a 1', 'kwarg: b 2' and 'kwarg: c 3'.
    Various Args    c=3    a=1    b=2             # Same as above. Order does not matter.

Positional and kwargs
    Various Args    1    2    kw=3                # Logs 'arg: 1', 'vararg: 2' and 'kwarg: kw 3'.

Named and kwargs
    Various Args    arg=value      hello=world    # Logs 'arg: value' and 'kwarg: hello world'.
    Various Args    hello=world    arg=value      # Same as above. Order does not matter.
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it,  Though this is not using "embedded arguments" and @keywords, but the more typical way of 4 spaces. 

I am looking a way to do this with embedded. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-names